# Find moment of inertia around two axes of sulphur dioxide

Tags: physical-chemistry, symmetry

Problem:

> Find the moment of inertia for 2 axes of $\ce{SO2}$. The rotational constants are  given in $\pu{MHz}$. The answer is required to be $10^{-46}\rm~ kg\cdot m^2$, 7 digit accuracy.

I used $$I = \frac{h}{8\times\pi^2\times B}$$ but the answer is marked wrong. I do not understand what I am doing incorrectly. I thought maybe that $\ce{SO2}$ is asymmetric so that formula will not work.

This is an online course that has  minimal discussion assistance. I have scrounged on Google & physical chemistry textbook to see what the alternative could be. Did not see another formula. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please take your time and format yuor post with the [MathJax syntax](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) so that we have a better idea of what you’re saying.

Comment: First question for you is what is the geometry of sulfur dioxide? Next, how many unique principle axes does it have?

Answer (score 1):

Without explaining some more its hard to help, but the most likely error is in using the wrong units. The rotational constant is usually given in wavenumber units (cm$^{-1}$), e.g. 2.02736 cm$^{-1}$. In a linear molecule the equilibrium value is

$B_e = \frac{h}{(8\pi^2cI)}$

with $B_e$ in wavenumbers and c is the speed of light in cm/sec. In your case since the SO$_2$ is not linear (its planar bent at the S atom, C$_{2v}$ point group) there are three rotational constants usually called A$_0$, B$_0$, C$_0$. 
 (You can check the units by converting Joules in to base units, m, kg, s etc . The moment of inertia is in kg m$^2$ and $10^{-46}$ is of the correct order of magnitude. Seven decimal places seems too many as the rotational constants are not usually known to more than 5 places.)

Comment: Thank you. But I am back at square 1. I can't use the formula B = h/(8(pi^2)I)?
 I thought that Ia = h/(8(pi^2)Ba). And the same for Bb. The problem requires 7 digit accuracy.
**For the vibrational ground state, the rotational constants, A and B, are 60778.79 MHz and 10318.10 MHz, respectively. Calculate Ia and Ib (Unit: 10^−46 kg m2, 7-digit accuracy). **
The moments of inertia around the principal axes 

Ia=(2mOmS/M)*r^2*cos^2⁡(θ/2)
Ib=2mO*(r^2)sin^2(⁡θ/2)
Ic=Ia+Ib
mO and mS are the masses for oxygen and sulfur, respectively. M≡mS+2mO is the mass of SO2.*

Comment: Could it be I must convert MHz to joules?

Comment: I thought I was going koo-koo. I was going over & over what I was doing wrong for this problem. I am REALLY sure I put in the same answer that I did just now - i did the SAME CACULATION. Now I got the green check - for this problem. What happened before? Who knows with MOOC graders! Thank you for the response to help!

Comment: please tick and markup if the answer was helpful.

Comment: I appreciaite the answer but it did not help. Fortunately  I had the right answer - it was the  course grader that malfunctioned.